# django built-in class based view - Where is self.object from?

Tags: python, django, class

In the following code, I don't understand something about the object.

```
class SingleObjectMixin(ContextMixin):
    """
    Provide the ability to retrieve a single object for further manipulation.
    """
    model = None
    queryset = None
    slug_field = 'slug'
    context_object_name = None
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    query_pk_and_slug = False

    ...
    
    ...


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Insert the single object into the context dict."""
        context = {}
        if self.object:
            context['object'] = self.object
            context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(self.object)
            if context_object_name:
                context[context_object_name] = self.object
        context.update(kwargs)
        return super().get_context_data(**context)
```

There is an attribute `self.object'`in the method `get_context_data.` I would like to figure out where the attribute `object' is created from.

Comment: The self.object in a Django class-based view is a property of the view. It is typically used to store the current object that is being operated on. For example, when creating a DetailView, self.object will be used to store the instance of the model that is being viewed.

Answer (score 0):

`SingleObjectMixin` is a mixin normally used by views. E.g. `BaseDetailView` uses this mixin where its method `get` sets the object:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/c8eb9a7c451f7935a9eaafbb195acf2aa9fa867d/django/views/generic/detail.py#L108

The following website gives you a great overview and description of all class based views and some mixins:
https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.1/django.views.generic.detail/BaseDetailView/